# Convert native javascript loop into lodash/Bluebird module loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, bluebird

I don't want to use the native javascript loop in the below code. How can I replace it with looping functions provided by lodash or bluebird modules?

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){           
    var name = relation[arr[i]];
        _.each(name, (n) => {
            if(!_.includes(arr, n)){
                arr.push(n);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: bluebird would be a poor choice as there is nothing asynchronous requiring promises - isn't this code already using lodash? _.each / _.includes?

Comment: I want to replace the loop in the first line .i,e  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)

Comment: replace it with what? something like `_.each` that you have used 2 lines later?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add values to arr while I'm iterating over it. If I do _.each, loop would never iterate over the newly added values.

Comment: right, so what you want is to do something that would break your logic - what's wrong with code that does what you want?